# Geometry Nodes "distribute points evenly on Faces"

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

is it possible to **distribute points** like array modifier on faces using Geometry Nodes?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would the Raycast node do what you have in mind? If you're not familiar with it there are several tutorials on YouTube about it. Maybe this one would help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wFaODMBxZD4

Comment: i'd like a more general way to do it (which is support any othe geometry shapes), with Raycast i think it takes lots of time to do it.